# Why is my matrix loading from csv working incorrectly?

Tags: c++, csv, matrix

Code that loads matrix from csv:

```
ifstream in;
in.open("matrix1_100.csv");
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
    {
        in >> matrix1[i][j];
    }
}
in.close();
```

N is correctly equal to 100.
How csv looks like:
[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cfhY.png)

What is loaded into the matrix:
[what gets loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp8UK.png)
If you can't see the picture - only first element from csv loads correctly (position 1, 1 in csv), rest of matrix are zeroes. If I use rand to fill in matrix instead it fills all correctly. I feel so dumb. This must be something obvious and it's the only thing that stands between me and completion of this project.

Comment: you need to read/ignore the commas or use a CSV parsing library

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alan! I used sstream and converter and now it works. I need more sleep. :)